# WCF call needs to receive a GENERIC param that can receive a list of different "Types"

Tags: wcf, generics

What is the recommended way to provide a WCF call that has a "Generic" param... something like this.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDbSync
{
   [OperationContract]
   void UploadTable(Data<T> table);
}
```

...where
*one client* might upload `Data<User_Entity>`,
*another client* might upload `Data<Address_Entity>`

**...all using the same procedure call**

Is this possible with Generics or am I supposed to create one OperationContract x List ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have a method that takes an open generic type. You can have methods that take a closed generic type.

If you want to have overloading in your WCF methods you should make sure that the operation name is unique (by using the `[OperationContract(Name=...)]` attribute)

Comment: so you are saying that the only thing I can do is play with the naming but conceptually, i need to write one procedure x List<Type>. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes. It's not possible to have a generic parameter but you could have all the List<SpecifiedType> methods and use overloading so the end user won't see the difference as long as you supply all the possible overloads (Maybe use a T4 to create them?)

Comment: I'm writing the client too ..so maybe is not too much of a problem. Do you know a good Tutorial for T4?